# Help coming up with a solution to a combinatorial problem

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, dynamic-programming, approximation, discrete-mathematics

So here is the problem:

Say I want to find the only possible combinations to find the sum of a specific number using only the numbers 1, 2, & 3 with a specific number of additions.

I know this sounds confusing, but let me give an example:

Say we were trying to find the number of possible combinations to add up to the number 6 using, as stated above, only the numbers 1, 2, & 3 with exactly 2 additions.

The solution is easy:

Since we are trying to add up to 6 using exactly 2 additions with the only three numbers we are allowed to use (1, 2, & 3), we only get: {3 + 3}.

Similarly, If we were trying to find the number of possible combinations to add up to the number 4 with exactly 2 additions we get: {1 + 3} & {2 + 2}.

So, I am asking is there an algorithm out there that I can use to solve this when the numbers get bigger? Is there a clever way to solve this with code? I've been thinking about this for a while and can't seem to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: [Also posted on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/306411/34181).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is using generating functions.  The number of ways to get the number 6 using "2 additions" of 1, 2, or 3 is the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(x+x^2+x^3)^2$.   This generalizes: the number of ways to get the number $n$ using "$k$ additions" of 1, 2, or 3 is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x+x^2+x^3)^k$.  I'll let you play with some examples to see why this is so.

Once you know this fact, you can then use [polynomial multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Polynomial_multiplication) and [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to compute the polynomial $(x+x^2+x^3)^k$ and then read off the answer.

See also [Calculating the number of multiplications necessary to evaluate a polynomial](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/44418/755).